# PHP post array to java servlet using cUrl

Tags: java, php, json, servlets, curl

I'm trying to post the following example array, from php, to a java servlet:

```
$tags = $tagger->tag($nlquery);
$js_string = json_encode($tags);    
echo $js_string
```

result:

```
{"Example","NN"},{"1","NN"}
```

cUrl code:

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/first/SPARQL");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $js_string);                                                                  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($js_string)));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $response;
```

java servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        String jsonData[];

        jsonData= req.getParameterValues("js_string");
        for(int i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(jsonData[i]);
        }
```

However this results in a `NullPointerException` on the java-side at the `jsonData.length` line. Am I passing the $js_string wrong from the php side? Or is their something wrong with the java-side code?

Update:
Using the following code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (req.getInputStream()));
        String str = br.readLine();
        String[] jsondata = new String[]{str}; 
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < jsondata.length;i++){
            System.out.println(jsondata[i]);
        }
```

returns the right result `{"Example","NN"},{"1","NN"}` however, now I can't loop through it because it doesn't see it as a multidimensional array. This is the code I worked with before using the servlet (static, for developing purposes)

```
String[][] phpsearch ={{"Example","NN"},{"1","NN"}};
for(int i=0; i<phpsearch.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("loop "+i);
                if(phpsearch[i][1]=="NN"){
                    result=searchLabel(phpsearch[i][0].toLowerCase());
                    System.out.println("array "+phpsearch[i][0] );
}
}
```

Maybe not so effective but atleast it works:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (req.getInputStream()));
        String str = br.readLine();
        str = str.replace(",", "|");
        str = str.replace("}|{", ",");
        str = str.replace("}", "");
        str = str.replace("{", "");

        String[] rows = str.split(",");
        System.out.println("rows");
        for(int i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("loop "+i);
            System.out.println(rows[i]);
            //System.out.println(jsondata[i][1]);
        }

        String[][] jsondata = new String[rows.length][]; 
        int r = 0;
        for (String row : rows) {
            jsondata[r++] = row.split("\\|");
        }
        System.out.println("jsondata");
        for(int i=0; i<jsondata.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("loop "+i);
            System.out.println(jsondata[i][0]);
            System.out.println(jsondata[i][1]);

            //System.out.println(jsondata[i][1]);
        }
```

Results in a 2 dimensional array, just like the above static example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (req.getInputStream()));
String str = br.readLine();
System.out.println(str);
// JSONObject data = new JSONObject(str);
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried it but it says: The constructor JSONObject(String) is undefined

Comment: @vincentkleine remove last line and just print the `str` and check if it has the data

Comment: aah yes it has the data! I can use it in an array, but is there anyway I can use it in a 2 dimensional array?

Comment: @vincentkleine I think using [`org.json.simple.JSONObject`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_java_example.htm) would be benifitial here